# Is there an alternative for Gnome Clocks on macOS?

Tags: gnome, macos, software-rec

Gnome Clocks is a quite handy app. Is there a “drop-in replacement” for it on macOS? I haven't found any app that combines all functionalities of the former.

Comment: This is for https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In macOS Monterey, there are desktop widgets, one of which is for time.

Comment: @JRFerguson unfortunately the widgets do not provide timers, alarm or chronometer funcionality.